# Sum of Factorials Error

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the sum of a factorials up to a number.  So if I gave it 3 it would return 3! + 2! + 1!.  Here is my code so far:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class sumOfFactorial { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(sum(n));

    }

    public static BigInteger sum(int n) {
        return factorial(n).add(sum(n-1));
    }

    public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
        BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
        if (n == 1) return BigInteger.ONE;
        else return x.multiply(factorial(n-1)); //error occurs here
    }
}
```

For some reason it gives me a Stack Overflow error at the indicated spot.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You can debug the code and figure out where it diverges from expected behavior.

Comment: Try to put in factorial function if(n<=1) instead of if(n==1)

Comment: If the input is too big, it might give you a `StackOverflow` because you're doing too much recursive calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nesting two recursive methods, `sum` and `factorial`.  However, your `sum` recursive method doesn't have a base case.  Like `factorial`, it must have a base case.  Make sure `sum` stops recursing at a base case, which in your case appears to be `n` equals `1`.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem.  Thanks!  Included the base case in sum, and it worked perfectly.  Will accept this as an answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

one of your problems is here

```
public static BigInteger sum(int n) {
    return factorial(n).add(sum(n-1));
}
```

try

```
public static BigInteger sum(int n) {
    if(n > 1){
      return factorial(n).add(sum(n-1));
    } else if (n < 0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("factorials are not defined for negative integers");
    } else {
      return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `n > 1` and `return` 1 in the `else` case?

Comment: @nhgrif because that will return 1 for n == 0.

Comment: I'm not a math person.  What should negative factorials return?

Comment: my mistake 0! is apparently 1 and -n! is undefined have edited answer